# Deploy .net core 2.2 web app on remote Kestrel Server?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, tfsbuild, kestrel-http-server

This question is in 2 parts.

1. I have successfully installed .net core 2.2 libraries on the Windows 2012 server. Now after this How to setup Kestrel Server on the Windows Server 2012 R2?
2. I am using TFS to release the build of my core web app directly to the Win 12 Server Kestrel server. How to do this? Permissions issues are already resolved.

Comment: Kestrel isn't a standalone web server. It's the server used by the web app itself. As the tag you used says `is built-in to ASP.NET Core`. [Hosting and deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-3.0) are covered in the documentation extensively. The [Kestrel page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.0) explains how it works, and when/how to configure it to use another server as a reverse proxy

Comment: You don't need to set up anything to use Kestrel. Just deploy your application. If you publish a self-contained executable, you don't even need the runtime. In many cases though, *especially* for publi-facing sites, you'll need a reverse proxy  in front of it. Another option is to use in-process deployment with *IIS*

Comment: Sounds like you didn't even go over the initial guide to ever publish an ASP.NET Core app onto IIS, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio Do that at least once so as to know what steps are, and it should be quite clear what's needed on the server, and what steps you can automate via TFS.